# Added additional fields to custom table in Acumatica has caused error. How to resolve?

Tags: acumatica

We added a number of additional fields to a custom table in Acumatica.  One of the fields is causing an error.  We made change in SQL Server and updated the code.  The field having the error is defined in the code:

```
#region LastRevisionInventoryID
[PXDBInt]       
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Revision Inventory ID")]

public int LastRevisionInventoryID { get; set; }

public class lastRevisionInventoryID : IBqlField{}

#endregion
```

The code validates and publishes but we get the following error when we try to open the screen after adding the fields to the screen.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.]
_SetValueByOrdinal(ItemBaseDocument , Int32 , Object , 
PXCacheExtension[] ) +1012
PX.Data.PXCache`1.SetValueByOrdinal(TNode data, Int32 ordinal, Object 
value, PXCacheExtension[] extensions) +84
PX.Data.PXCache`1.a(TNode A_0, TNode A_1, IDictionary A_2, 
PXCacheOperation A_3, Boolean A_4) +1273

[PXException: Error: An error occurred during processing of the field 
LastRevisionInventoryID : Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object..]
PX.Data.PXCache`1.a(TNode A_0, TNode A_1, IDictionary A_2, 
PXCacheOperation A_3, Boolean A_4) +2908
PX.Data.PXCache`1.a(TNode A_0, TNode A_1, IDictionary A_2, 
PXCacheOperation A_3) +87
PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(IDictionary values) +237
PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteInsert(String viewName, IDictionary values, 
Object[] parameters) +187
PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.a(Object[] A_0, Object[] A_1, String[] A_2, 
Boolean[] A_3, PXFilterRow[] A_4, DataSourceSelectArguments A_5) +1783
PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, 
DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) 
+13769
PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, 
DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) 
+211
PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, 
PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) 
+65
PX.Web.UI.PXFormDataProvider.DataBind() +381
PX.Web.UI.PXBoundPanel.PerformSelect() +134
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +138
PX.Web.UI.PXDataViewBar.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +33
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +162
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
+6925
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I removed the reference to the new fields that had int datatype and now it is working without any issue.  Why would the following code cause an error:

Comment: #region LastRevisionInventoryID
    [PXDBInt]       
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Revision Inventory ID")]

    public int LastRevisionInventoryID { get; set; }

    public class lastRevisionInventoryID : IBqlField{}

    #endregion

Comment: See answer below. The same error will be generated again until you change all your custom field types to Nullable types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Acumatica, all DAC fields must be of a nullable type, `Nullable<int>` or `int?` in your case:

```
#region LastRevisionInventoryID
public abstract class lastRevisionInventoryID : IBqlField { }

[PXDBInt]       
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Revision Inventory ID")]
public int? LastRevisionInventoryID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)